# Showing that it is not possible that for every $q_j$ from a finite set of odd primes, it holds that $2+\prod_{k \neq j} q_k $ is divisible by $q_j$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

This a repost of a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4277799/130022) which was asked at MathStackExchange, but got no answer so far, so I am trying here.

Let $n\ge 1$ and let $Q= \{q_1,\dotsc, q_n\}$ be a set of $n$ odd primes, all different and such that  $Q \neq \{3\}$.

> Show that there is no such set $Q$ such that for every $q_j$ it holds that
> $2+\prod_{k \neq j} q_k $ is divisible by $q_j$

(with the convention that an empty product is $1$).

Clearly this is true when $n=1$ since in this case, $q_1 \neq 3$.

This is also true for $n=2$ since if $q_1 < q_2$ and $q_1$ divides $q_2+2$, it is not possible that $q_2$ divides $q_1+2$.

For $n=3$, this is shown as follows: suppose that there exist three odd primes $p< q < r$ such that $3\le p \lt q$ and $r\ge 7$ such that $p$ divides $q\cdot r +2$, $q$ divides $p\cdot r +2$ and $r$ divides $p\cdot q +2$, then $p\cdot q$ divides $p\cdot q \cdot r^2 +4 +2r(p+q)$, then there exists an integer $K$ such that $K\cdot p\cdot q=1+r\frac{p+q}{2}$. But $ \frac{1}{p\cdot q}+ \frac{r}{2q}+ \frac{r}{2p} \le \frac{1}{15}+ \frac{r}{10}+ \frac{r}{6}= \frac{1+4r}{15}$.
Then $ 1 +r\frac{p+q}{2} \le \frac{1+4r}{15} p\cdot q$ , then $K \le \frac{1+4r}{15}$.  On the other hand, $r$ divides $p\cdot q +2$ then $r$ divides $K\cdot p\cdot q+ 2K= 2K+1 + r\frac{p+q}{2}$, then $r$ divides $2K+1 \le  \frac{17+8r}{15}$ then $7r \le 17 $ which contradicts $r\ge7$.

It can be shown that a similar proof (showing a contradiction on the size of the largest member of $Q$) works as long as $n\le 8$. The case $n=9$ does not bring a contradiction but a finite limit ($958$) to the size of the largest member of $Q$, then the case $n=9$ can be settled by checking a large but finite number of cases.  Hence, should such a set $Q$ exist, it has to contain at least $10$ different prime numbers. Similarly, this method shows that if $3$ is not allowed, $Q$ must contain at least $28$ different prime numbers.

For the context, I have found that a proof of the above statement for any $n$  would imply that the conjecture raised in [Trying to prove a power sum divisibility conjecture](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4273287/130022) is true:

> For positive integers $a$ and $n$, $2a + 3 \nmid 1^n + 2^n + \dotsb + (a - 1)^n + a^n$.

I would also accept as an answer a disproof of the above claim or the exhibition of such a set $Q$.

Comment: The condition can be reformulated as follows: $2/(q_1\dots q_n)+1/q_1+\dotsb+1/q_n$ is an integer. This makes it clear that $n\geq 9$, for otherwise the above expression is less than $1$. BTW I suspect that there is a counterexample, it is just hard to find.

Comment: This is a nice reformulation - I wonder if there is anything special about $2$ here other than that it is coprime to all the $q_j$.

Comment: when $2$ is replaced by $7$,  and all the allowable  $q_j$ coprime to $7$, a solution exists : $Q=\{3,5\}$.

Comment: May be $2$ is special just because it is smaller than than all the $q_j$, and this would raise the question what happens when $2$ is replaced by $1$.